# angular translate service for sentence

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-translate

I would like to translate by angular translate service a bug sentence.
The sentence is contained words that are in the dictionary.

For example:
I got the sentence from server.
"Toni the cat $EATED TWO MOUSES$ $BASED_ON$ their $SMELL$"

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app .config(["$translateProvider",
function ($translateProvider) {
            $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
                prefix: "common/lang/lang-",
                suffix: ".json"
            });
            $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

}]);
```

I have a two files for translate - English and Portuguese dictionary:

lang-en.json:

```
{
"$EATED TWO MOUSES$" : "eated Two Mouses",
"$BASED_ON$": "based on",
"$SMELL$": "smell"
}
```

Also i have a json file for Portuguese.

I have a div and i put :

```
<div class="headline" ng-bind-html="element.headline">{{element.headline | translate}}</div>
```

Any suggestions?
Maybe i need to split the sentence and translate specific words?
I tried to use

```
  $scope.translated = $translate($scope.element.headline);
```

But it returns only a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to have variables in the sentence you need to use `{{value}}` syntax instead of `$value`. Then you could you something like this:

```
{{element.headline | translate: {value: 'value'} }}
```

If you want to use translation in your controller/service then you'd better use `instant` method:

```
var options = {value: 'value'};
$translate.instant(element.headline, options);
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Well, first of all you cannot translate parts of the sentence. You need to `key` for whole sentence and parametrize it if needed. So you have to create translation like `'WHOLE_SENTENCE' : "Toni the cat {{EATED TWO MOUSES}} {{BASED_ON}} their {{SMELL}}"` and then use `{{'WHOLE_SENTENCE' | translate: { 'EATED TWO MOUSES': value1, ...} }}`.